# Content of size X was truncated to 65536. Apache Nutch

Tags: apache, solr, nutch

I have problem with parse command in Apache Nutch  when i want to crawling urls and i found the solution by myself.

In Apache Nutch there is a default configuration in *nutch/conf/nutch-default.xml* that you can find the property with name `file.content.limit` and change the default value to whatever you want.

> ```
> <property>
>   <name>file.content.limit</name>
>   <value>65536</value>
>   <description>The length limit for downloaded content using the file://
>   protocol, in bytes. If this value is nonnegative (>=0), content longer
>   than it will be truncated; otherwise, no truncation at all. Do not
>   confuse this setting with the http.content.limit setting.
>   </description>
> </property>
> ```